# Changing value in pointer to pointer

Tags: c++, pointers

So i have a function similar to that (simplified example):

```
void somefunction(structuraltype *something) {

    something->variable = 6;

}
```

And as you can see i can easily access values using ->

But i realised that i must use pointer to pointer instead of a single pointer.
Can you please explain to me how should i access value in this situation?

```
void somefunction(structuraltype **something) {

    something???variable = 6;

}
```

Comment: Why do you need to use a pointer-to pointer?

Comment: try with: (*something)->variable = 6;

Comment: There is no reason why the function you have shown needs to take pointer to pointer. It doesn't need a simple pointer argument either. Make the argument a reference.

Comment: Before, i used the function only to read variable values. But now i need to change them too. If i don't use additional pointer, value can't go outside of a function.

Comment: This is incorrect: "If i don't use additional pointer, value can't go outside of a function". You don't need to use pointers at all. Pass the argument by reference.

Comment: In C+ you do have the luxury of references

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf well, I do need to use at least one pointer because in original function what I pass is pointer to a Linked List.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equivalent of this:

```
void somefunction(structuraltype* something) {
    something->variable = 6;
}
```

is this

```
void somefunction(structuraltype* something) {
    (*something).variable = 6;
}
```

You can apply that for every level of indirection:

```
void somefunction(structuraltype** something) {
    (*(*something)).variable = 6;
}
```

The outer level of indirection can always be replaced by  `->` as in:

```
void somefunction(structuraltype** something) {
    (*something)->variable = 6;
}
```

But it's probably more usual to use a reference to a pointer than a ponter to a pointer:

```
void somefunction(structuraltype*& something) {
    something->variable = 6;
}
```

Comment: That will come in handy too, I will comeback here to check everytime I need it

Answer (score 4):

Simply dereference the first pointer to access the second pointer, which you can then use to access the object members:

```
void somefunction(structuraltype **something) {    
    (*something)->variable = 6;    
}
```

Comment: This answers the technical but it is not a good direction to go for a novice. Would you advice a novice driver to tank up with water in order to save gasoline? It certainly does that, technically: it's technically a good answer.

Comment: @TheSorter: Remy is just harvesting rep points, in my opinion. Otherwise he would care about what he's teaching you.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Why would you say something like that? Have you seen his work? I think you are wrong.